# Не могу настроить репозиторий GitHub

Tags: github

Выдает ошибку:

> git clone git@github.com:vitaly28/java-counta.git
>
> C:\Users\вит>git clone git@github.com:vitaly28/java-counta.git Cloning
>   into java-counta'... The authenticity of host 'github.com
>   <192.30.253.112>' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8. Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting ?
>   ................................................................. C: \
>   Users \ вит> git clone git@github.com: vitaly28 / java-counta.git
>   Клонирование в java-counta '... Невозможно установить подлинность
>   хоста github.com <192.30.253.112> '. Отпечаток ключа RSA - SHA256:
>   nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8. Вы действительно хотите
>   продолжить подключение <да / нет>?
>   ...................................................................
>   git clone git@github.com:vitaly28/java-counta.git
>
> fatal: destination path 'java-counta' already exists and is not an
>   empty directory

Answer (score 1):

у Вас поменялся ключ или на сервере гитхаба поменялся. А может быть кто то Вас прослушивает и подменил ключ. Если ключу доверяете, то запустите bash-терминал, откройте файл

```
vim ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

найдите там отпечаток нажмите слеш <kbd>/</kbd> и начало хеша `nThbg6kXUpJWG`, потом <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Должно подсветить одну строку. На ней нажимаем дважды <kbd>d</kbd> и сохраняем файл <kbd>Esc</kbd> (на самом деле здесь эта кнопка не объязательна) <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Теперь можно повторить подключение явно

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

и подтвердить принятие ключа.

Comment: javac Calculate.java

Comment: javac Calculate.java
java Calculate
Все работает
git add Calculate.java
и на все остальные команды Выдает ошибку
fatal: Not a gei repository <or any of the parent directories>: .git

Comment: javac Calculate.java
java Calculate
Все работает
git add Calculate.java
и на все остальные команды Выдает ошибку
fatal: Not a gei repository <or any of the parent directories>: .git

Comment: javac Calculate.java

java Calculate

Все работает

git add Calculate.java

и на все остальные команды Выдает ошибку

fatal: Not a gei repository <or any of the parent directories>: .git

Comment: Объясните пожалуста что такое ключ Нужно по новой зарегистрироваться ?

Comment: Что такое ключ Github    ?

Comment: Пересмотрел. Вы пытаетесь склонировать проект в папку, где уже есть проект. Склонируйте в соседнюю.

Comment: Не совсем понял у меня же один адрес SSH